# Is it normal to receive that many GET requests when running rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server

Whenever I run rails server, it starts logging a lot of GET requests, specifically to the compiled Style Sheets files (every half a second or so.) 
They look like this:

```
Started GET "/assets/application.self-0c7a55ee32b2e31e48453f9129ff2cd12bc8eb34c8a0e51e59e9f4a6adda82cd.css?body=1&_=1450936645614"
```

I wouldn't mind about them, but my laptop battery drains pretty quickly when running rails server, and I don't know if this is the cause.

I would really like to know if this is normal behaviour. And, if it is not, then what could be the cause that many requests per second.

Thank you very much!

**EDIT:**

Here is my show your config/enviroments/development.rb file, @uDaY

```
Rails.application.configure do
config.cache_classes = false
config.eager_load = false
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
config.active_support.deprecation = :log
config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
config.assets.debug = true
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true
end
```

Comment: show your config/enviroments/development.rb file

Comment: This is definitely not normal. Do you do some kind of Javascript polling combined with HTTP headers that suppress caching of assets?

Answer (score 0):

The `_=1450936645614` part in the query is generally a trick adopted by the jQuery AJAX component to work around asset caching.

This makes me think you have some sort of component that is configured to periodically hit your app.

You can use a tool such as the Google Chrome Developers Tool to inspect the requests sent by your browser and determine who is the culprit.